# DomPDF Put 2 tables side by side

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I´m using DomPDF to generate a PDF in PHP. I need to put 2 tables side by side.

```
    <table style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
        <tr style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">names</td>
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">salary</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Pedro</td>
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">1500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Jhon</td>
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">450</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
        <tr style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Brand</td>
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Color</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Ferrari</td>
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Green</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Daewoo</td>
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Blue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Chevrolet</td>
            <td style=" border: 1px solid black !important;">Gray</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried to put display:inline-block; on the tables but I've got a FatalThrowableError.

```
Call to a member function get_cellmap() on null
```

I tried to change display:inline-block to float:left but I've got something like this

[image]

They were "side by side" but just the content moved to right. Borders are wrong.

How can I put 2 tables side by side using DomPDF?.

Comment: did u try setting a `width`

Comment: Yes but still the same problem.

Comment: @VíctorCardozo did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @VíctorCardozo did you try display:inline?

Answer (score 0):

Setting position:absolute on 2nd table and adjusting per right/left/top/bottom css did the trick for me